# Redshift : Check upload Result from STL_LOAD_ERRORS on Windows Batch

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

We're copying S3 uploaded files to Redshift by Workbench/J in our batch as follows;

```
java -jar %WBJ_DIR%\sqlworkbench.jar -profile='%WBJ_PROF%' -script='%ScriptFile%' -displayResult=true
```

- Script File is copy command, created precedingly, according to target tables and conditions(used as file name, 'yyyy-mm-dd_TABLE_NAME.gz').

So far, uploading task is going successfully, but we'd like to add any error captures to confirm upload result on Redshift.

Just wondering if there is any option like 'SET NoCount ON' in SQL Server.
If only get record count, with no header and no message, I think we can get the upload error count from STL_LOAD_ERRORS on our batch like this;

```
    --Check SQL
    set COMMAND=select count(*) from STL_LOAD_ERRORS where filename='%COPY_FILE%' and starttime > '%bat_start_time%';

    -- Get Error Count
    for /F "delims=" %%A in ('%COMMAND%') do (
    set REC_CNT=%%A
)
    echo Upload Error Count : %REC_CNT%
```

Of cource, any other good way to confirm the uploaded result on Redshift would be appreciated.

Thank you so much for your useful advice in advance.